# Does __forceinline perform faster than __inline?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++

Some functions are too short, so is it a good place to use `__forceinline` instead of `__inline`?

```
__inline void foo(){ //Optimized call
//some commands
}

__forceinline void fast_foo(){ //More "inline" - Does it perform faster than inline?
//some commands
}
```

Comment: If the function would have been inlined anyway they are equivalent.  If not, the only way to know is profile.  Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Does __forceinline perform faster than __inline?

Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not. It all depends on what's inside the function, the patterns of calling, and lots of other factors.

In general, predicting performance accurately from a static analysis is close to impossible. If you want to answer the question accurately, time both alternatives.